# android WebView alternative for webapps

Tags: android, performance, web-applications, webview

WebView does have many html5 features but lacks performance needed to
display dynamic content. *Are there any other bare bone web browsers
better suited as a platform for web applications on Android?*

Here is a simple example which performs extremely bad on my device and
the emulator:*emphasized text*

http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/116_parallax/tutorial-source-files/tut-index.html

- transition animation nearly freezes
- hover effect in navigation lagging (when using a mouse)

Comment: I'm struggling with performance of Androids WebView, too. Tomorrow I will try [Embedding Cordova WebView on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android) hoping now that it would be faster. If there's another implementation I will be grateful to hear about :)

Comment: nope, it only extends normal WebView for PhoneGap. Does'nt include any improvements of html5/css3-performance :(

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well.  In my case, I keep reloading a site that has javascript enabled and the javascript just randomly stops running at times.  If I quit the app and restart, then it starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you try chromium_webview. It has diverse features plus better performance. Here is link of this project on [Github](https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview).